# Active Directory users on Multiple Domains

Tags: windows, active-directory

Hope someone can help me.

I have a task to create a new active directory domain - which i have no issues doing. However those guys would like to get users from an particular OU from an corporate domain to the new domain, so the users reamains on both domains, so when a user leaves they account is disabled on corporate domain and those settings are passed to second domain.

Can this be achieved?

Comment: If for only a dedicated OU, yes but it need to be coded, with [ADSI integration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms677626%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in example, as it's not a builtin possibility.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick responds - so what do you think is the best aproach moving forward - creating a new Forest domain or creating a child domain. We want the users to come to our second domain  because we want to this domain to activesync to one login, and when a user leave than the corporate team disable the accounts syncs to our new SD either a new forest or chid? and than is passed on to onelogin..  but i want to know is possible to bring only a set of users from corporate domain

Comment: (previous comment deleted, as it was typed some later than your clarification)

Comment: The way I told, you can't sync password, but you can manually bind each user, and validate if they are desactivated, to desactivate on the second domain. Your request to bring only some user is the killing point.

Comment: Thank you - thats right - we want to bring to new domain only the dev team not everyone - so the dev team come to new domain they have full controll to this domain however the dev team does not want to manage the leavers process - so leavers is still done via corporate process..

Comment: Perfect, then ask your dev team to code the thing with ADSI integration.

Comment: lol - thanks i dont think they will do - so this is only achievable through the ADSI integration?  so the parent , child  and trust relation ship will not work?

Comment: No, but why you dont make a child domain, and just give a group 'domain' admin' membership there ? Technicaly any user would be able to lauch a session there, but only those users would be admin.

Comment: The reason we want a new domain for the dev team is that we will be able to join their devices into the network as currently they have local authentication. so by bringing the users from the corporate AD to our dev enviroment ad and we can do so much with our AD for example use onelogin for the SSO etc